# How to add a new record with an existing primary in microsoft access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am having a problem in executing one of my system's features (a parking registration system)

I have set the relationship to a many-to-many relationship which many students are able to register many vehicles.Right now I can't find any solutions on how to add a new record while using an existing primary key (in this case, is the student's id number) A very clear guide would be much appreciated!

Comment: Seems you're looking for a tutorial of some kind. This site will help you with a *specific* issue, which you haven't described in an answerable way.

Answer (score 1):

A Primary Key, by definition, must be unique for every record.  The Primary Key in your table should be neither the StudentID nor the VehicleID.  Those should be the Primary Keys within the Student table and the Vehicle table respectively, but the table that stores all of your data should use a separate Autonumber field as a Primary Key.

Comment: Sorry if i wasnt clear enough, but my question is, a student has already registered in my system, now all of a sudden he/she wants to add a new vehicle into his/her registration.In my form, i directly store the data into the Vehicle Table.So how am I able to enter that new record by avoiding update anomalies/without leaving any important keys null such as StudID in the Student Table?

Comment: Either create one field in your Vehicles table and call it StudentID (do not make it a Primary Key), create one field in your Students table called VehicleID (not advised, because if a student registers 2 vehicles you're screwed) or create a completely separate "crosswalk" table with 3 fields; ID, StudentID and VehicleID.  If you use the 3rd method, you just need to join the Students table to StudentID and the Vehicles table to VehicleID and you'll always know which vehicles belong to which students.

Comment: Ok when i reviewed back, the table which has a null value by the time insert the new record in the vehicle table,is my Registration Table, which consist of attributes RegNumber, StudID , VehiclePlateNo and RegDate. The StudID and VehiclePlateNo are the foreign keys and the ones which has null values are the StudID and RegDate.